# Error while updating app on google play console

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-play-console

I'm getting error while updating app on google play console. **I provided right key and password.** But still having error. How to fix it? can you help ?

**Error i'm getting on google play console**

Upload failed : 
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you sign the APK with the same upload key that you used to sign the first APK that you uploaded on the play console. If you've lost the key you can contact google support.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423